# Would specifying $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) support arm64 in valid architectures?

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit, arm64

Was wondering what would be the impact if we specify $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) as architecture but still have arm64 in as a valid architecture?

Comment: It will use the intersection of the two as supported architectures.